# Enum name not recognized when used as a return type

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-3.7, type-hinting

I have this Python 3.7 code:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class MyClass:
    def calculate(self, data: str):
        new_state: Optional[State] = self._get_state(data)

    def _get_state(self, data: str) -> State:
        state: State = State.DEFAULT
        return state

class State(Enum):
    DEFAULT = auto()
    STATE_1 = auto()
```

PyCharm has an issue with the return type of the `_get_state` method, reporting this: `Unresolved reference 'State'`. When I try to run the code, I get `NameError: name 'State' is not defined`.

However, the `State` references `new_state: Optional[State] = _get_state()` in the `calculate` method and `state: State = State.DEFAULT` in the `_get_state` method work just fine.

Why is this?

Comment: You need to define the `State` class before you define `MyClass` so you can refer to it in type annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type annotations in function signatures are evaluated at the time the class is defined, not when they're called. So you need to define the `State` class before defining `MyClass`.

The annotations in the function bodies aren't processed until the functions are called, that's why they still work in either order.